# Error trying to list out key/value pairs in python of empty dict

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, reduce

I'm trying to list out key/value pairs in a python dict similar to if it was formatted by the perl expression `"@{[%cats]}"` using this expression:

```
print(f"{LIST_SEPARATOR.join(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,cats.items()))}")
```

Given this for cats: `{'Buster': 'myCat', 'Felix': 'herCat'}`, I get the expected value of `Buster myCat Felix herCat` (`LIST_SEPARATOR` is normally one space).

However, if cats is `{}`, I get `TypeError: reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value`.  How do I get an empty result for when cats is an empty dict and the desired result if it has keys/values?

Comment: Not an endorsement of this code, but FWIW the error is telling you what's wrong. `reduce` takes one more argument for the initial value. If you pass that in, your error goes away: `functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,cats.items(), ())`

Answer (score 2):

Do **not use `reduce` with concatenation to flatten a sequence!**  This is a classic example of a "Shlemiel the Painter algorithm". It is quadratic time, and will scale terribly. This can be done trivially in linear time. So instead, use either this nested list comprehension idiom:

```
LIST_SEPARATOR.join([item for tup in cats.items() for item in tup])
```

Or use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
LIST_SEPARATOR.join(chain.from_iterable(cats.items()))
```

Note, also, that the `sum` builtin, which is the equivalent of `reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, ...)` actually *explicitly prevents you from using strings*.

Comment: Thank you - I'm going to use the chain approach!

Comment: I had to add a map operation for when the values are not strings (the keys are always strings): LIST_SEPARATOR.join(map(_str, itertools.chain.from_iterable(cats.items()))) - where _str = lambda s: '' if s is None else str(s)

Answer (score 0):

works for both:

```
#cats = {'Buster': 'myCat', 'Felix': 'herCat'}
cats = {}
print(' '. join([k + ' ' + v for k, v in cats.items()]))
```

Comment: So this would be LIST_SEPARATOR.join([k+LIST_SEPARATOR+v for k,v in cats.items()]) - thanks!  I'm kinda liking the "chain" approach below where I only have to mention LIST_SEPARATOR once.